# Open Source Parental Control for Windows

Tags: windows, open-source

anyone knows any "real" parental control software for windows which is "open source"?

tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just found one:
[Kid Logger](http://kidlogger.net/)

Comment: not open source

Answer (score 1):

Real "parental control" on Windows is Windows itself.

1. add all allowed domains and their IP's (twice each, with and without 'www') in file /windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts
2. in properties of network connection go to properties of TCP/IP, choose 'use the following DNS addresses' and add 127.0.0.1

Now your system knows IP's of domains listed in hosts, and cannot query DNS for others, so no connection.

Answer (score 0):

While not "open source," [Microsoft's Windows Live Family Safety](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-family-safety?os=other) is nice. It's free and works great with Vista/Win7.